# Solaris) Can I set Run Control to change shell on boot?

Tags: shell, solaris

```
#passwd -e
Current Shell : /bin/ksh
New Shell : | (cursor)
```

My question is, can I bind some scripts in `/etc/rc3.d/` that can answer the cursor part with a pre-written line of command?

I've tried `passwd -e ; /sbin/sh` and obviously failed.

Comment: You want your legacy service startup scripts to pre-populate a text field in something that is not a service? (Something tells me `expect` could be useful, but not in your `rc*.d` directories)

Comment: It looks as if you're looking at possibly implementing the same functionality as [`chsh` from other Unix systems](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh). Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe you can use [usermod](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/usermod-1m.html) instead of passwd.